# Preferred way to find values within a string - PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am getting a response back from PayPal in NPV form so I use `explode("&",$response)` to separate out the return values but I fear that in the future if they mix their string up (like start it with ACK instead of TOKEN), my code will be returning the wrong value.

My full code:

```
list($token,$timestamp,$correlation,$ack,$version,$build) = explode("&",$response);
```

The string looks like this: `TOKEN=EC-3RC2692512364446&TIMESTAMP=2014-02-07T00:52:51Z&CORRELATIONID=e8467b1c30fb7&ACK=Success&VERSION=109.0&BUILD=9605603`

Any suggestions on a better way to go about getting the values of each 'string' within this string? I was thinking `strstr` or even `strpos` but I am not certain on this. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Looks like you can use [`parse_str()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) on that, as it resembles a query string.

Comment: Any respectable API should have a dev mail list that outlines changes, migrations, and shelf life of API versions. Hopefully you can stay ahead of any application breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = array();
foreach (explode("&", $response) as $entry) {
    list ($key, $val) = explode('=', $entry);
    $results[strtolower($key)] = $val;
}
```

Now you can access `$results['token']`, for instance.

You could also use `parse_str()`, which parses data that looks like a URL query string. If they encode special characters using percent-encoding, this will handle that for you.

Comment: Exactly what I knew I was missing! Thank you for this gem. I'm reading up on these php functions, lots to learn. I just tested the above and it works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach(explode("&", $response) as $val){
$exp = explode("=", $val, 2);
${strtolower($exp[0])} = $exp[1];
}
```

Then you may check whether or not the variables have been actually created:

```
var_dump($token);
var_dump($timestamp);
var_dump($correlationid);
var_dump($ack);
var_dump($version);
var_dump($build);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly check the resultant variables for string length and also if they contain specific characters / digits, etc., as well. This will allow you to be notified if the string has been mixed in the future and possibly to revert some unwanted action.

Use [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) to get and verify the string length.

Check if `$ack` variable starts with `"ACK"` using

```
strpos($ack, "ACK") === 0
```